# fail to run Vulkan on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, vulkan

the code on github [SaschaWillems/Vulkan](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan.git) runs smoothly on WIN10 with a VERY old GPU GT730, but when i wanna run it on ubuntu,  i encounter a lot of problems. here is a breaf of my system:
    Operating System | Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
    Graphics Card | GeForce GTX 1080
    Driver | 430.50
    SDK Version | 1.1.121.0
but when i run Vulkan, it will return ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED.

so i follow the guide of ["Getting Started with the Vulkan SDK"](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.1.121.0/linux/getting_started_ubuntu.html) on the lunarg website, i install the vulkan-sdk first:

```
      wget -qO - http://packages.lunarg.com/lunarg-signing-key-pub.asc | sudo apt-key add -
      sudo wget -qO /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lunarg-vulkan-xenial.list http://packages.lunarg.com/vulkan/lunarg-vulkan-xenial.list
      sudo apt update
      sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
```

then i run vkvia as told, the return error shows "Vulkan failed to find a compatible driver", so i follow the doc and then find ["Vulkan Graphics Driver Problems"](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.1.121.0/linux/via.html#user-content-vulkan-graphics-driver-problems). the doc tells that there are possiblely 4 kind of reasons:

```
     1. hardware not support Vulkan. but i found on nvidia website GEDORCE GTX 1080 is OK for vulkan1.1
     2. driver not support Vulkan. but i found on nvidia website driver 430.50 is OK for vulkan1.1
     3. no Vulkan driver with support for the OS. i am running on ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS, 
     4. driver failed to install properly. But i can use nvidia-smi to show the card, and i can run my other code on this GPU without VULKAN
```

if i run vulkaninfo, the error info is vulkaninfo.c:6155: failed with VK_ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

hope someone can help me! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
sudo apt-get install libvulkan1 libvulkan1:i386 mesa-vulkan-drivers mesa-vulkan-drivers:i386
```

You can test with vulkan tools:

```
sudo apt-get install vulkan-tools
vulkan-cube
```

Comment: `vulkan-cube` is `vkcube` in some versions

Answer (score 0):

One thing that worked for me is to follow the [Vulkan Tutorial for Development Environment](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Development_environment#page_Linux). It goes through the packages required to have it running.

In my case I ran

```
sudo apt install -y vulkan-tools libvulkan-dev vulkan-validationlayers-dev spirv-tools libglfw3-dev libglm-dev
```